# Spring mapping a .jsp with parameters to a .jsp (404) error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a 3rd party .jsp that I am trying to use in my SpringMVC 3.2 application.

the URL call looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/dms/pcc.jsp/Page/q/0/AttributescumentID=eJQAyAEYASgBJAFMAMgAlADIARgBsAG8AZwBvAC4AdABpAGYA0
```

I am getting a 404 error. How do I map this in my web.xml?

when I call

```
http://localhost:8080/dms/pcc.jsp
```

it works (well, no 404 errors) but I need to send it the parameters.

Changing the 3rd party jsp might be problematic, so how does one map this call straight to the jsp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Really a broad question. I would start with checking mapping in `@Controller`, then move into application-config.xml and then web.xml.

It would be nice if you would look at sample Spring Application.

Answer (score 0):

If call to `http://localhost:8080/dms/pcc.jsp` works, you should try following thing.

```
http://localhost:8080/dms/pcc.jsp?AttributescumentID=eJQAyAEYASgBJAFMAMgAlADIARgBsAG8AZwBvAC4AdABpAGYA0&otherParams=something
```

The `Page/q/0/` part in URL seems to be messing things up for you. If these also are parameters to be sent, send it the way explained above.